# Tkinter canvas.after skipping all my prior code

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to learn python but no matter where I look I can't seem to find an answer for this or anyone else having this problem at all, so I'm wondering if I'm just doing something wrong myself as even when my online instructor does the exact same thing, they do not get this problem. We're trying to make flash cards for study with a built in timer to flip them after 3 seconds using Tkinter. We're using pycharm if that makes any difference.

Here's my code.

```
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"
import pandas
file = pandas.read_csv("data/french_words.csv")
from tkinter import *
import random
start = 100




def new_flash_card():
    x = random.randint(1, start)
    canvas_front = Canvas(width=800, height=526, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas_front.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
    canvas_front.create_image(410, 263, image=front_image)
    canvas_front.create_text(400, 150, text="French", font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))
    canvas_front.create_text(400, 263, text=f"{file.French[x]}", font=("Ariel", 60, "bold"))



def flip(y):
    canvas_front.itemconfig(card_title, text="English")
    canvas_front.itemconfig(card_pic, image=back_image)
    canvas_front.itemconfig(word_title, text=f"{file.English[x]}")

window = Tk()
window.config(height=800, width=800, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, padx=50, pady=50)
back_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_back.png")
front_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
right_image = PhotoImage(file="images/right.png")
wrong_image = PhotoImage(file="images/wrong.png")
canvas = Canvas()
wrong_button = Button(image=wrong_image, highlightthickness=0)
wrong_button.grid(column=1, row=1)
right_button = Button(image=right_image, highlightthickness=0, command=new_flash_card)
right_button.grid(column=0, row=1)
canvas_front = Canvas(width=800, height=526, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
canvas_front.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
global start = 100
x = random.randint(0, start)
card_pic = canvas_front.create_image(410, 263, image=front_image)
card_title = canvas_front.create_text(400, 150, text="French", font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))
word_title = canvas_front.create_text(400, 263, text=f"{file.French[x]}", font=("Ariel", 60, "bold"))
canvas_front.after(3000, flip(x))

window.mainloop()
```

I have yet to make the code that will remove the card from the deck if they get it right, but without providing files, I have a list of 100 french words and their english translations and each card should show the french side first for 3 seconds then flip to the english side until the user presses one of two buttons. Here in lies the problem, if I leave out the code that includes canvas_front.after(3000, flip(x)),
the program runs by instantly giving me a french word, but no english word. If I press the button, I get a new french word. If I leave it as it is, it waits for 3 seconds and gives me only an english word, and the button press waits 3 seconds and only gives me english words, I never see the french. I don't know what's happening but my after command is for some reason cutting out all code before itself and I cant figure out how to bypass it. I've had this same problem with the after keyword in tkinter before but was allowed to bypass it by using the import time method but I am specifically not allowed to do that for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable to a function call scheduled with `after`, you need to use a [lambda](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) like so:

```
canvas_front.after(3000, lambda: flip(x))
```

As written, `canvas_front.after(3000, flip(x))` calls `flip` immediately, which isn't what you want. Using a `lambda` instead allows you to call an anonymous function that then calls `flip(x)` *for* you as scheduled.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick and correct response. My instructor never once mentioned that or used it but it seems to work for her without it in her videos.

Comment: This is not true. You can absolutely do `after(3000, flip, x)` ... and should. Why bury a function in a lambda if you don't have to?

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a lamba. You can pass positional arguments when using `after`.

Comment: I honestly wasn't aware - that's good info! Thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling your function instead of passing a reference to it. The syntax you want is:

```
canvas_front.after(3000, flip, x)
```

`after` has the following signature.

```
#after(milliseconds, call this function, with these args)
after(milliseconds, function_reference, *function_args)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @JRiggles - I was tempted to change your answer instead of write a new one, but I was afraid that my change would be considered "too intrusive" and I didn't want to get in trouble. I did wait a bit after writing my comment to see if you would change your answer.

Comment: No worries - I wasn't on later in the day yesterday, so credit where credit is due. And changing it seems disingenuous since I literally had no idea you could do this haha. I appreciate you not editing my answer all the same.

Comment: FYI `after_idle` works the same way, except you don't provide milliseconds. `after_idle(func_ref, *func_args))`. The only thing you may need a `lambda` for is `bind` and really only when you want to send more than just the event to the callback, but there is a better way to do this too. It's just to much to explain in a comment.

Comment: This is all great info - `lambda`s with `bind` makes sense, and I've definitely used it there. Does `after_idle` just toss the call into the event loop and tkinter gets to it when it has a chance?

Comment: `after_idle` runs as soon as tkinter is idle, which is most of the time so, in a lot of ways `after_idle` is "right now".

Comment: Nice - that could definitely come in handy! Thanks for taking the time